# 301 redirect to the page without slashes at the end and remove one catalog level

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How to set 301 redirect from the site pages with one, two or more slashes to the page without slashes

for example:

FROM

```
http://site_name.com//
http://site_name.com///
...

http://site_name.com/somepage//
http://site_name.com/somepage///
...
```

on

```
http: //site_name.com
```

and still need to cut catalog:

FROM

```
http://site_name.com/catalog/catprod/someproduct
```

on

```
http://site_name.com/catprod/someproduct
```

p/s: Sorry for the translation

Comment: have any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following redirect

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^//+(?:catelog/)?(.*)/*$ /$1
```

Comment: have any ideas how to do it?